# JSON Funtions for SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with a column that contains this kind of structure:

```
{"code":"SUCCESS","error":null,"result":{"payload":[{"id":1973519169,"accountId":698782,"status":"CAPTURED","referenceCode"...
```

How can I extract the "id" or "status" fields using JSON functions?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want one row for each array element in `payload`?

Comment: Please tell us what you tried so far and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this one (get array from json, and get json from this array after):

```
    WITH
        t AS (SELECT '{
          "code": "SUCCESS",
          "error": null,
          "result": {
            "payload": [
              {
                "id": 1973519169,
                "accountId": 698782,
                "status": "CAPTURED",
                "referenceCode": "test"
              }
            ]
          }
        }'::JSON as arr)
    SELECT json_array_elements(arr -> 'result' -> 'payload') -> 'id' as id
        FROM t;

1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 34 ms (execution: 5 ms, fetching: 29 ms)

id: 1973519169
```

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=97e1fb5ab93ad031c66a2ecf4771ca1f)